# How to inspect for object properties in android device/emulator for Automation testing using Selenium android driver?

Tags: android, android-emulator, firebug, selenium-webdriver

We have a mobile web application that opens only in default browser in mobile device. So having tough time to get the properties[ID/Class/Xpath..] of objects for Automation testing using selenium android driver. At present I am doing a reverse way where collecting all the properties of objects in a page. But this is very tedious. Is there any other utility to get the properties of elements just like firebug in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I have started using the xpath viewer for chrome which works well

which allows you to view xpaths and css paths for any element on the page.

I am sure plenty of similar add-ons exist for other browsers.

such as [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) which allows you to view xpaths

also [FireFinder](http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/12/firefinder-for-firebug-an-extension-to-quickly-find-elements-matching-your-css-selectors-or-xpath-expressions/) allows you to find both xpaths and css paths..

Personally I suggest css selectors would be better, they would be less brittle.

Comment: Could you name some of them?